# Working on a finite subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems, map-projections

Let $X$ be a normed space and $L$ a finite dimensional linear subspace.

I need to show that there exists finitely many $l_1,.....l_n \in L$ and $f_1,.....f_n \in X'$ such that $$ l = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(l)l_i$$ for all $l \in L$
Since L is finite it has as basis, so there are $l_1,.....l_n \in L$ with coefficients $f_1,.....f_n$ depending on $l$ such, that we have $$ l = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(l)l_i$$

But how do I show that those $f_i$ are in $X'$??

More I need to show that there exists a continuous projection $P: X \to L$.

So I need to show that $P(X)=L$ and $P^2=P$. Can I define the projection the following? $$ Px = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x)x_i$$

P continuous: $$||\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)l_i||_L \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}||f_i(x)l_i||_L \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\|f_i\|_{X'}\|x\|_X \|l_i\|_L \leq .....$$

I am very thankful for help?

Comment: Define your $f_i$ on $L$ and use Hahn-Banach. For the second task you have the right idea, just replace $x_i$ with $l_i$, what should the $x_i$ even be?

Comment: Thank you! @LeBtz Why can I assume that the $f_i$ are in L'?

Comment: Because $L$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: AH thanks, can you help me why P is a continuous projection then?

Comment: Yeah I tried to show continuous with the definition of bounded operators. Could be correct, but I am not sure, but I dont know how to show that it is a projection?

Comment: Please add what you have tried in your question. For showing it is a projection: Why don't you just check if the definition holds by calculating $P^2x$?

Comment: I added it, but it is not done :(

Comment: And I tried, but I dont know how to work with the sum in there..

Comment: You can take $\|x\|$ out of the sum and are left with a finite sum independent of $x$. For the projection thing: Use linearity of $P$ to deal with the sum.

Comment: Ah thanks, ja with the linearity I get $sum f_i(f_i(x)l_i)l_i but how do I go on to that?

Comment: You need to think of the definition of $f_i$ to evaluate $f_i(f_i(x)l_i) = f_i(x)f_i(l_i)$.

Comment: but I just know that they are functionals on X'? Is that enough?

Comment: That is not true. You have defined them on $L$ in a specific way. Since $l_i$ is an element of $L$ you can apply this definition.

Comment: What exact definition are you refering to?

Comment: You defined that yourself. For $l\in L$ you defined $f_i(l)$ to be the unique Element such that $l = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(l)l_i$.

Comment: But then I don't really use the linearity right?

Comment: Of course we use that. We only need the definition to evaluate $f_i(l_j)$ for $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$ because that is what is left when you use linearity in $P^2x$.

Comment: But we have $P^2x = \sum f_i ( \sum f_i(x)l_i)l_i$ and what we have as the argument of the first $f_i$ is equal to x?

Comment: I'll write you an answer because I don't think that you will get it yourself, sorry. I tried really hard.

Comment: Oh okay, well thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

All that is left is, to show that $P^2 = P$.

Since the $f_i$ are defined on $L$ in such a way that $f_i(x)$ is the unique coefficient of $l_i$ in the representation $x = f_1(x)l_1+...+f_n(x)l_n$ and we have $l_i = 0l_1+...+1l_i+...+0l_n$ we have $f_i(l_j) = 1$ if $j=i$ and $f_i(l_j) = 0$ if $i\neq j$.

This yields $$P^2x = P(\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)l_i) = \sum_{j=1}^nf_j\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)l_i\right)l_j = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)f_j(l_i)l_j = \sum_{j=1}^nf_j(x)l_j = Px,$$

where we used that each summand vanishes unless $i=j$ in the second last equality.